# Instant run in Android Studio 2.0 (how to turn off)

Tags: android, android-studio, settings, android-instant-run, instant-run

How to disable Instant Run in Android Studio 2.0 Preview. When I go to the settings I see it:

[image]

and I can not remove the tick from "Enable Instant Run..."

I use Android Studio 2.0 Preview 9, but this error was present in Android Studio 2.0 Preview 7 also.

Comment: You need to check your gradle version from project `build.gradle`.

Comment: I had exactly same problem with same message because I opened settings before project was loaded. Re-opening settings after a while fixed my problem and I was able to uncheck that checkbox.

Answer (score 234):

**UPDATE**

In Android Studio Version 3.5 and Above

Now Instant Run is removed, It has "**Apply Changes**". See [official blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/08/android-studio-35-project-marble-goes.html) for more about the change.

> we removed Instant Run and re-architectured and implemented from the
>   ground-up a more practical approach in Android Studio 3.5 called Apply
>   Changes.Apply Changes uses platform-specific APIs from Android Oreo
>   and higher to ensure reliable and consistent behavior; unlike Instant
>   Run, Apply Changes does not modify your APK. To support the changes,
>   we re-architected the entire deployment pipeline to improve deployment
>   speed, and also tweaked the run and deployment toolbar buttons for a
>   more streamlined experience.

Now, As per stable available version **3.0 of Android studio,**

If you need to turn off Instant Run, go to

> **File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run** and **uncheck Enable Instant Run**.

[image]

Comment: No, I still see that I have shown in the screenshot. I can not turn off this feature

Comment: If you see some really weird problems crop up (after changing resource xml files, for example) - try turning off instant run or uninstall your app to force a re-install.  I lost a couple of hours chasing a "phantom" problem that was instant run related - so now I just turn it off and sip some beverage while compiling / installing.  The app in question is huge (a derivative of iosched) and so is pretty impossible to try to isolate a test case to submit to google, sorry about that...   Life is too short to spend all of it isolating test cases, have to move on with what works.

Comment: Didn;t you see that he IS NOT ALLOWED to uncheck it. For me it's not an answer

Comment: Check android studio version mentioned in my answer and try again hope that helps

Comment: update to latest stablel version 2.1.2, your problem will be solved that is a beta version of studio.@murt

Comment: @AmitVaghela I meet this issue even on 2.1.2 , however I fixed it somehow, but dont remember currently how..

Comment: there are some bugs in instant run function please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/37207831/2826147.

Comment: In recent version of Android Studio (I have checked 2.2.2) the "settings" is merged with "SDK Manager". This option is NOT available from File menu ( now it is File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings), as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I'm using version 3.0 of Android Studio and the box for enabling Instant Run is grayed out, so I can't uncheck it. How can I solve this?

Comment: try, installing again after uninstallation of android studio.

Comment: This proposed remedy worked for me. I was able to immediately build, install the apk and run the app.

Comment: This works, are there any downsides to disabling *Instant Run*?

Comment: @JMK no, there are no downside of disabling.

Answer (score 40):

Using `Android Studio newest version` and update Android Plugin to 'newest alpha version`, I can disable Instant Run:
[image: Android studio Instant Run view with Version highlighted]
[image: Android studio Project view with Android Plugin Version highlighted]

**Try to update Android Studio.**

Answer (score 13):

I had the same exact isuue with the latest **Android Studio 2.3.2** and Instant Run.

here what I did : (I'll give you two ways to achive that one disable for specefic project, and second for whole android studio):

1. **if you want to disable instant-run ONLY for the project that is not compatible** (i.e the one with SugarORM lib)

on root of your projct open gradle-->gradle-wrapper.properties then change the value
 `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip`

and
 on your project build.gradle change the value

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```

### [image]

2. **If you want to disable instant-run for all project (Across Android Studio)**

in older version of AS settings for instant run is

```
File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings ->Build,Execution,Deployment
```

However 
**In most recent version of Android Studio i.e 2.3.2** , instant run settings is:

- for Android Studio Installed on Apple devices -> **Preferences...** (see following image)
- for Android Studio Installed on Linux or Windows -> in **File-> Settings...**

[image]

[image]

---

Edited: If for any reason the Instant-run settings is greyed out do this :

```
Help-> Find Action...
```

[image]

and then type 'enable isntant run' and click (now you should be able to change the value in Preferences... or file->Settings... , if that was the case then this is an Android Studio bug :-)

[image]

Comment: The solution for only one project downgrades to a much older version of gradle, which shouldn't really be recommended as it also disables a lot of other new features and potentially is a security risk. This should be stated in the post.

Answer (score 12):

Turn off Instant Run from Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

the design in android 2.3 (stable version) is slightly changed.

> File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and
>   uncheck Enable Instant Run.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Update August 2019**

In Android Studio 3.5 Instant Run [was replaced](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/08/android-studio-35-project-marble-goes.html) with Apply Changes. And it works in different way: APK is not modified on the fly anymore but instead runtime instrumentation is used to redefine classes on the fly ([more info](https://developer.android.com/studio/run#apply-changes)). So since Android Studio 3.5 instant run settings are replaced with Deployment (Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Deployment):[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried all above but nothing helps, at last i just figured out that under setting >> apps, device still has an entry for uninstalled application as disabled, i just uninstalled from there and it starts working.

:) might be useful for someone