# How to open the device selector every time i run the app in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a real device and an emulator. When i first install the app , the IDE asks me to select between the two but on subsequent runs it does not ask me to choose. How do i get it to ask me every time? I tried clicking on stop app , but the problem persists.

Comment: Here you go (*Go to Run>Edit Configurations > Deployment Target Options and uncheck "Use same device for future"*) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36541902/device-chooser-dialog-is-not-showing-up-after-instant-run

Comment: Thanks ! It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy. In `android studio` please click your app name `dropdown` showing at the top menu then click edit configurations and `unselect` **`use same device for future launches`**

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! It worked.

Comment: @SushobhNadiger happy to help.happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can change it from Run -> Edit Configuration -> Deployment Target Options

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are stopping your app before next run. (You can find stop option on the same tools section )