# How to specify the device to run the app in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I have exactly the same problem as the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36541902/9398992)

However,the question was asked 3 years ago and the solutions are outdated.
The problem started after I updated android studio (now using :

**Android Studio 3.5
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312, built on August 9, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0**

)

So how to get the adb window ( or the device chooser window) back?

Comment: The list of available devices can be seen by clicking on the current device selected at the toolbar.

Comment: Wow I didn't see that,thanks it solved the problem.
should I delete the question ? @Edric

Comment: It's okay - you don't have to delete the question as this could be useful especially for others who were used to the old layout before Android Studio 3.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the device chooser dialog that used to show up in previous versions of Android Studio, it appears to have been moved to use a dropdown menu instead.

Anyways, the list of devices to run your application on can be seen when clicking on the target device dropdown-menu (which can be seen before the "Run/Play" icon):

[image: Screenshot of target device dropdown-menu (taken from Android developer docs)]

<sub>(P.S. Image attached above is from the Android developer docs.)</sub>

For more info on how to build and run your app, check out the [Android developer docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Select the device from there and click on Run.

[image]

You can now also run the app on multiple devices. If you select "Run on multiple devices" from the dropdown menu when you click on that.