# Instant Run not working

Tags: android, instant-run

**Precondition**

Since I use android studio 2.0 (Release version) I get many inner class erros when compiling my app (those seem to be not relevant, as the app still works fine). When I disable instant run, my app works perfectly fine, if I enable it, the app crashes

**Observations**

The errors while compiling are following:

```
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.e) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.a) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.b) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.c) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.samsung.android.sdk.pass.d) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.formats.jpeg.JpegImageParser$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.formats.jpeg.JpegImageParser$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.formats.jpeg.JpegImageParser$3) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.formats.jpeg.JpegImageParser$4) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.formats.jpeg.JpegImageParser$5) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.formats.jpeg.JpegUtils$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.formats.jpeg.exifRewrite.ExifRewriter$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.formats.jpeg.iptc.IPTCParser$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.formats.jpeg.iptc.IPTCRecord$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.formats.jpeg.xmp.JpegRewriter$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.formats.jpeg.xmp.JpegRewriter$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.formats.jpeg.xmp.JpegRewriter$3) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.formats.jpeg.xmp.JpegRewriter$4) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.formats.tiff.TiffElement$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.formats.tiff.write.TiffOutputDirectory$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.formats.tiff.write.TiffImageWriterLossless$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.formats.tiff.write.TiffImageWriterLossless$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.icc.IccConstants$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.icc.IccConstants$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.icc.IccConstants$3) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.icc.IccConstants$4) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.icc.IccConstants$5) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.palette.MedianCutQuantizer$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.sanselan.palette.MedianCutQuantizer$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

Afterwards I get errors when starting the app like following (ONLY with instant run enabled):

```
com.app.test.data.DataManager$ExistingDataSources; Incompatible class (SUID): com.app.test.data.DataManager$ExistingDataSources: static final long serialVersionUID =4867698184298054210L; but expected com.app.test.data.DataManager$ExistingDataSources: static final long serialVersionUID =2877622586407293138L;
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.app.test.data.DataManager$ExistingDataSources; Incompatible class (SUID): com.app.test.data.DataManager$ExistingDataSources: static final long serialVersionUID =4867698184298054210L; but expected com.app.test.data.DataManager$ExistingDataSources: static final long serialVersionUID =2877622586407293138L;
```

Complete log is here: https://gist.github.com/MFlisar/3514ad2af4b4de692d228da0e1264015

**Question**

What does that mean for me? That I have to clone all libraries that are mentioned in the big build error block and compile them locally instead of importing them via gradle?

Comment: what are the logs when app crashes??

Comment: It seems a proguard issue. Have you added `-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable` ?

Comment: I added a gist with the complete relevant log... @PedroOliveira I have disabled proguard for debug builds... Adding the proguard rule does not change anything...

Comment: @PedroOliveira but lets say this is DEV version, why would you have ProGuard on in DEV version/flavour?

Comment: @Marko I use proguard on dev versions. Using proguard doesn't mean obfuscation. I use it to avoid multidex. It just removes methods that are not used. Keeping the line table and all that stuff is still possible to debug.

Comment: @prom85 Instant run has a lot of known bugs and you could be facing one of those :\

Comment: @PedroOliveira I am aware of that, specially the multidex one, which sucks... Just tought it would be better to disable it in DEV, because ProGuard needs some time to run, which makes building the app longer than without ProGuard.

Comment: You're right about that. If you can't afford to get that overhead then it's better to disable it. But that "overhead" allows me to reply comments in stackoverflow :)

Comment: Hi, have you solved it? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: No. I just disabled it. Is not working for me even with the newest android studio version...

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37207831/2826147) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37207831/2826147) SO answer

Answer (score 3):

What is happening is that you didn't define your own `serialVersionUID` for your serializable class and so the JDK compute its own. However the computed version differs when building with Instant-Run (IR) enabled vs disabled.
So using a version of the app with IR will fail to reload serialized classes built without it since the UID is different.

The solution is to define your own `serialVersionUID` in all the classes that you serialize. [It's best Java Serialization practice anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it)

Comment: I've just read about it CommonsWare's block... I'll check that. I'm quite sure that I manually defined the UID back then, but I'll retry that...

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Instant Run solved issues I had with Services, Classes and Fragments

> Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run > Uncheck "Enable Instant Run"

However, if you want to keep Instant Run you can try by just UnChecking "Restart Activity on Code Changes"

> Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run > Uncheck "Restart Activity on Code Changes"

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

There are many bugs introducing by **[Instant Run](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html)** but they became less and less in newer versions. You should update latest stable version of android studio and be sure about check Gradle plugin also If you don't still find a solution with it then disable Instant run, you can do it as per other answer suggests or see this question [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168753/instant-run-in-android-studio-2-0-how-to-turn-off) Also i found **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37207831/5476209)** pretty useful.

You can **[submit bug here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Studio%20bug)** about it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to proguard-rules.pro

```
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
```

This error may happen almost all classes which has InnerClasses, I think. (like support.v4 etc) for me.

I've tested on Android studio 2.2
(Not tested log4j. Tested support.v4 etc.)

build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
...
minifyEnabled true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
...
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
}
```

getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt') also works.