# random "no executable code found on line" while debugging in android studio when using "instant run"

Tags: android, android-studio, instant-run

So I m using latest **android studio 2.1 beta 2** , tried almost everything, now even I use `minSDK 22` and `targetSDK 23` and still I have random problems with instant run.

Any workarounds ?

Am I only one with this ?

I did not find any bug report or anything.

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37207831/2826147) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35169716/2826147) answer

Answer (score 0):

Seem to work now. Maybe they just fix it in latest build.