# Android studio: How to force re-installation (Disable instant run for once)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-run

I am aware that you can fully disable instant run(the new Android 2.0 functionality). However I do like the feature except in some cases:
-When making changes to a layout file, it often does not pick up the changes causing Nullpointer when accessing those resources.

Is there a way to bypass instant run? And force a re-installation?

I do know that changes the AndroidManifest forces this but that's not convenient.

Comment: (Disable instant run for once) means what ?

Comment: The new functionality in Android studio 2.0. It patches your application on the device instead of redeploying the full application.

Comment: i know that check my answer to disable it http://stackoverflow.com/a/35169716/2826147

Comment: I do not want to disable it permanently. Just once when needed

Comment: you have to enable/disable it when needed.

Comment: Just clean your project? then hit the run button like you would normally do and AS will rebuild it from scratch

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Android Studio 2.0, 2.1 and 2.2:

If you need to deploy a clean build, select `Run` > `Clean and Rerun 'app'`  from the main menu, or hold down the `Shift` key while clicking `Rerun`. This action stops the running app, performs a full clean build, and deploys the new APK to your target device.

See also the [Instant Run documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run), paragraph "Using Rerun"

## Android Studio 2.3:

The behaviour of Instant Run has changed in Android Studio 2.3

[image: Run] `Run` Force a cold swap and an app restart. If you make a change to the app manifest or a resource referenced by the manifest, Android Studio always pushes your changes with a full APK reinstall.

[image: Apply changes] `Apply changes` Push certain code and resource changes to your running app without building a new APK—and, in some cases, without even restarting the current activity.

Comment: Needs updating for AS 3.x, sigh.