# Issue in gradle 2.1.0 : Application launches with delay of 5-6 seconds

Tags: android, performance, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an application which was working fine with gradle 1.5.0. Application use to launch instantly after gradle build.

But when I changed the gradle to gradle 2.1.0 it launches with a delay of 5-6 seconds for first time after gradle build. I have tested with some of my other apps also in those apps also same issue persists.

Then I changed the gradle version back to gradle 1.5.0 then again my app started working fine without any delay.

So, it seems like there is an issue with gradle 2.1.0.

Moreover, I noticed one more thing that when I run the app with gradle 2.1.0 then the cache memory of app shows around 11-12 MB after first time launch without performing registration or any other action in app

While on running with gradle 1.5.0 cache memory size remains around 15-17KB.

Comment: in new android studio there is new feature instant run which make first build slow

Comment: @KhizarHayat i'm not saying that build is slow. I'm saying that after build is complete then there is delay in launch. Same issue is reproduced when you simply clear app data and then launch your app by tapping on you app icon.

Comment: when you disable instant run this delay will gone

Comment: @KhizarHayat you are absolutely correct its working fine now. thanks

Comment: Please don't use code markup for anything other than code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue came in new android studio version due to instant run feature when you disable instant run feature first time launch delay will be gone.

Comment: how to disable instant run

Comment: see link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168753/instant-run-in-android-studio-2-0-how-to-turn-off

Comment: @VeereshCharantimath goto settings and search instant run. Then uncheck the first option.