# It's taking very long for MainActivity to get called

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

My Application class is simply this

```
public class DogApplication extends Application {
    private static DogApplication context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = this;
    }

    public static DogApplication getContext(){
        return context;
    }
}
```

Yet it's taking about 10 seconds before my MainActivity gets called. How do I know? I am logging the timestamp in my Application#onCreate, MainActivity#onCreate start and end. Basically right after the open bracket I log the timestamp and then log again right before the closing bracket. Here is the result of my login:

> DogApplication: Start of DogApplication onCreate is 1466143820699
>   MainActivity: Start of MainActivity onCreate is 1466143820870
>   MainActivity: TIME TO traverse onCreate is 3260 ms

based on this data MainActivity shouldn't be taking that long to show up. And yet when I install my app, a white screen shows up for about 10 seconds before any view or content is visible. I don't have a splash screen. What might be causing this? I support api 11 and up.

Comment: You need to add MainActivity as it is taking time not the Application class.

Comment: Post you MainActivity's onCreate, that is the time consuming method

Comment: Do you run your app on Device or on Emulator? Is it an Apk or do you load it from an IDE, if so, wich? More details please.

Comment: Are you using instant run in android studio ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue came in new android studio version due to instant run feature when you disable instant run feature first time launch delay will be gone.
To disable instant run see link [Instant run in Android Studio 2.0 (how to turn off)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168753/instant-run-in-android-studio-2-0-how-to-turn-off)