# PackageInfo versionName now says INSTANT_RUN

Tags: android, android-studio, manifest, package-info

It appears that Android Studio 2.2 Preview 4 substitutes "INSTANT_RUN" for the versionName in PackageInfo rather than what has been put in the manifest. **Is there any other way of seeing what is in versionName in the manifest?** The code I am using is:

```
gstrVersion = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
```

Comment: You could try disabling Instant Run.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really answer the question. I'm asking if there is an alternative way to the code I posted to see the versionName, not to limit the IDE functionality so my code works.

Comment: Try `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME`. As a bonus, since that's just a constant, it will be faster and use less memory. However, I don't know if that too gets mangled by Instant Run.

Comment: Thanks again, @CommonsWare, but it appears Instant Run mangles that as well, or rather both methods probably draw on the same base.

Comment: That's surprising. If nothing else, you can do it manually, adding your own `buildConfigField` that you populate in `build.gradle` with the same value as you use for `versionName`. Or, depending on where you need the value, use `resValue` to add a string resource with the version name.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question,

> **No, there is no other way to get version name from manifest.**

BUT Try

As commented by Sir CommansWare

you should disable INSTANT RUN,

> File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and
>   uncheck Enable Instant Run.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35169716/2826147) for more details

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really answer the question. I'm asking if there is an alternative way to the code I posted to see the versionName, not to limit the IDE functionality so my code works.