# Android - APK is different when device is unplugged

Tags: android

I'm using Android Studio 2.1.2.
Ok, this is probably ridiculous but when I debug/run my apk, it runs normal.
When I unplug my device from PC and runs, it doesn't load some features, like a fragment.

Have anyone experienced something like that?

Comment: Sounds like you're using instant run, turn it off.

Comment: You turn instant run off by gradle product flavor..in my set up debug runs instantRun than I have another gradle product flavor that install a beta to run at normal

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ptzar and @Fred Grott, I found the solution on this link: [Instant run in Android Studio 2.0 (how to turn off)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168753/instant-run-in-android-studio-2-0-how-to-turn-off)