# Android Studio - Can't Disable Instant Run

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, android-instant-run

I have a LibGDX project which is made up of a core project and multiple Android/desktop projects which are dependent upon it.

I'm currently changing some code in the core project but upon manually building, cleaning, and running the changes are not being reflected when I run the project.

From my searching I feel the issue is related to Instant Run, **but I cannot disable it** as the checkboxes are grayed out.

[image]

Is my issue related to Instant Run? And how would I go about disabling it?

Comment: Could it be already disabled since it says instant run requires gradle. When i first opened my project it was same as you but after gradle sync it turns to clickable. What do you think ? It can be gradle error. 
And i found same question also unanswered. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168753/instant-run-in-android-studio-2-0-how-to-turn-off

Comment: I was thinking this just now, was wondering how to "build with Gradle". I've clicked the Sync button and it does it's thing but still unclickable afterwards.

Comment: It appears you were on the right track, I noticed one of the modules in the build.gradle file were commented out. Uncommenting it and then re-syncing allowed the Instant Run buttons to be clickable. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @FTLRalph I'm having the same problem, could you explain how you solved it, please?

Answer (score 2):

it seems you need a successful build with gradle (at least up to the configuration phase) and then the checkbox gets editable.

Answer (score 1):

On a new installation of Android Studio 3.0.1, I found that I couldn't build a project because of Instant Run and that the Enable Instant Run was forced on and greyed out so that it couldn't be disabled.

The build error was:

```
Error:Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
```

I found that doing a build from the command line fixed both the failure to build and not being able to disable Instant Run.

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you change the Instant Run setting in a specific project.
I mean you need to do:

1. Open the specific project
2. Right click on the file
3. choose settings
4. Build
5. Instant run

For me its work