# Disable Instant Run for project

Tags: android-studio

I have a project that does not build if you try to build it with Instant Run enabled. That's why I would like to disable Instant Run for that project.

Can I do that in a way that can be committed to the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**if you want to disable instant-run ONLY for the project that is not compatible** (i.e the one with SugarORM lib)

on root of your projct open gradle-->gradle-wrapper.properties then change the value
 `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip`

and
 on your project build.gradle change the value

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```

[image]

**If you want to disable instant-run for all project (Across Android Studio)** see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44096317/5235263)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to turn off `Instant Run`  for a Project only till now available stable version of `Android Studio 2.3`

But to build the Project properly with Instant run enabled and it will not affect the project try to remove the `.idea` folder and `.gradle` folder, then click `Sync Project with Gradle Files`, when the process finished, try to run app.

Hope this solution works for you.