# Debug console doesn't show messages after upgrading Android Studio to 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio

I just upgraded the version of Android Studio to 2.3 and gradle to version 3.3 and I lost one of the most usefull features, the logs inside the Debug Console. When I run the app with Debug  mode the only Log that's being displayed inside the Debug console is this:

```
03/03 10:35:40: Launching app Split APKs installed 
$ adb shell am startservice com.myapp.android/com.android.tools.fd.runtime.InstantRunService 
$ adb shell am start -n "com.myapp.android/com.myapp.android.UI.SplashActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Connecting to com.myapp.android Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8601', transport: 'socket'
```

After that nothing is being displayed. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: which tab are you looking at? Run tab or Android Monitor tab?

Comment: it's at the bottom, right from "run" and left from "TODO"

Comment: the code you posted looks like its from the "Run" tab, "Android Monitor" tab is what your looking for. if your on that tab then you should restart Android studio or pc. if still a problem then you should submit bug report

Comment: It's almost the same output,but it's inside the "Debug" tab.

Comment: There are some exceptions that doesn't show up or it's hard to find them inside the Android Monitor, that's why I need the "Debug Console" to be working.

Comment: Debug tab will appear automatically, when you debug your app. Make sure to have break point.

Comment: Ditto - just upgraded myself from 2.3.3 to 3.3 (and additionally upgraded all suggested plugins) and now the Run and Debug windows no longer show Log output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log.d reports not showing up after Android Studio 2.3 Update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581935/log-d-reports-not-showing-up-after-android-studio-2-3-update)

Comment: Anybody with the right answer?

Comment: Same here, frustrating at the number of suggestions for using logcat in android monitor.  This wasn't the question, there are a number of clear benefits from using the console in the debug tool window.

Comment: You should edit some configurations. Check My Soloution [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576606/android-studio-2-3-debug-shows-connected-and-disconnected-lines-but-nothing-in/43362994#43362994).

Answer (score 9):

I don't know how to fix this (I hope someone figures it out soon), but here's an alternative:

1. Open the "Android Monitor" tab
2. Select the "logcat" tab
3. In the upper-right corner of the Android Monitor tool window, click on the drop-down menu and select "Show only selected application"

The output from Android Monitor is now almost the same as what it was with Debug. You can choose what information will be displayed before the messages by clicking the gear in the logcat's left sidebar.

You'll end up with something like this:

[image: logcat]

Comment: This is not a good choice because Android Monitor will clear out and replace with new info when app crash. You don't get a chance to see which part of code that make it crash.

Comment: @AzlanJamal This never happens to me when an app crashes. Could there be a setting in Android Studio that you've enabled that causes this to happen?

Comment: happens to me to, logcat is showing to much logs. you can isolate your app in the logcat but still shows only error logs, all info and system logs are gone.

Comment: Thank you, did the dev notes however pointed out this change ?

Answer (score 3):

go to File / Setting / Build, Execution, Deployment / Instant Run 
enable Log extra ...

now you have the log in Android Monitor tab (alt+6)

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem. it worked for me after i turned off Instant Run. After you turned it off run Debug. Then go at the Bottom to "Android Monitor" and then click on "logcat".
Here is a description how to turn Instant Run off:
[Instant run in Android Studio 2.0 (how to turn off)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168753/instant-run-in-android-studio-2-0-how-to-turn-off)

Answer (score 0):

I have't the same problem. See this bug report:

[Issue 236525:  Android Studio 2.3 and Gradle 3.3 update: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.InstantRunService Error: Not found; no service started.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=236525)

If it produce other errors you need to make a new simple project with the necessary parameters and try to run it on your device. It was helped for me. Good luck!!

I think this bug will fix in short time.

Answer (score -1):

i dont know the exact solution.but there is way to get the debug results

- go to Android Monitar tab.
- and set option to No filters at top ,right side  of the tab.
- and then start run/debug you will get all the results and also the whats are the errors in you application.

better understand purpose i post a picture  [image: here]