# Log.d reports not showing up after Android Studio 2.3 Update

Tags: android

After upgrading to Android Studio 2.3, my Log.d reports are no longer showing up in the run menu.  I rebooted my machine twice.  Strangely, the reports are showing up when I run an app on my physical device, but not for the emulator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432358/android-studio-logcat-nothing-to-show

Comment: I tried restarting the logcat, restarting studio twice and rebooting once.  Still no Log.d lines showing up in the 4: Run menu or the 6: Android Monitor.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

goto Run - Edit Configurations

then 2nd tab Miscellaneous

check both items `Show logcat automatically`and `Clear log before launch`

Comment: That did it Thanks!  At least they are showing up in the LogCat. They used to show up in the 4: Run menu as well, but it works for me.

Comment: Just had to do this *again* after upgrading Android Studio from 2.3 to 3.0.  Guess these were missed by the "import preferences from 2.3" process.

Answer (score 1):

According to this bug report, this seems to have been an intentional change in 2.3:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=235668

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: the mistake I was making was leaving out the message. For example I was only providing the first string parameter (the tag) and leaving the actual message out:

Log.d("MyTag", "")

When I stopped putting an empty string as the 2nd param and putting a random Char, or anything for that matter in the 2nd param then it showed up in my LogCat, otherwise it got skipped.

Hope this helps someone!