# Where are the Runtime messages and logs displayed in Android Studio 2.3?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-runtime, android-studio-2.3

The logcat was displayed in the run tab at the bottom-left of the screen.
But that is not showing the messages anymore after i updated the android studio and updated to the latest gradle version.

UPDATE:I am able to see the logcat in the Android monitor, but not in the run tab.
So how to show the logcat in the run tab? As was displayed earlier...

Comment: really? i also update same as yours but everything ok.. Have you invalidate/restart AS..or restart your PC?

Comment: Yeah, im not getting it, its like all of a sudden the run tab went blank and is just displaying only the commands used to push the app to the device.

Comment: You should edit some configurations. Check My Soloution [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576606/android-studio-2-3-debug-shows-connected-and-disconnected-lines-but-nothing-in/43362994#43362994).

Answer (score 0):

In android studio goto Tools->Android Device Monitor you got your logcat

**Step 1:**
[image]

**Step2** :[image]

**If you want to add it on Main Windows of Android Studio** :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i want the logs to appear in the run tab.