# Android Studio 2.3 debug console did not show anything useful

Tags: android, android-studio

Before I upgrade to Android Studio 2.3, I am able to get event and log from debug console tab. After upgrade to 2.3, this debug console tab like in image below did not show anything useful. I don't prefer using Android Monitor to see my logs because Android Monitor will clean and restart the info inside it when my app crash. I want to see where the crash happen, that's why information in debug console is very important to me. Anybody that have ideas on how to enable this again are really appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: In your log, I see there is "Disconnected from the target VM ...", may be your device is disconnect so you don't see the log

Comment: @PhanVanLinh I took the screenshot after device disconnected. In fact, it is quite uncommon for log to show connected and disconnected after one line without anything in between. I updated with new screenshot.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574428/debug-console-doesnt-show-messages-after-upgrading-android-studio-to-2-3)

Comment: @AtefHares like I said in the question above, Android Monitor is not a good choice for me because it cannot give me the info of where my app crash since it will clear out all logs after crash.

Answer (score 2):

You should edit some configurations.

Check My Soloution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576606/android-studio-2-3-debug-shows-connected-and-disconnected-lines-but-nothing-in/43362994#43362994).

Answer (score 1):

[image]there is a way to get the debug results in android 2.3 ...

go to Android Monitor tab.and at rightside set No filter option ..

if you cannot understand click link to see the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOBeQ.jpg)picture [android 2.3 get debug results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOBeQ.jpg)

Comment: This log should to show debug messages, prints stack traces on errors and other debug information but it not show anyone in Android Studio 2.3

Comment: if you set right side top option as a "No Filters" you will get all the details of your app like debuging and if you set right to third one as a " Warn"  you will get the errors that your app crash location .

Comment: I talk you about debug log which not show me any messages. But you talk me about logcat it is not the same. If you don't know the answer plz don't spend our time.