# What does the logcat warning `Unknown element under <manifest>: meta-data` mean?

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest, logcat

While running a a freshly installed app, I find this `Warning` messages in the logcat:

```
W/PackageManager( 1233): Couldn't remove dex file for package:  at location /data/app/xx.yy.zz-1/base.apk, retcode=-1
I/SmartHeartBeat( 1233): listenAppUpdate, package: xx.yy.zz has been Updated
W/PackageParser( 2909): Unknown element under <manifest>: meta-data at /storage/emulated/0/xxx/zz.apk Binary XML file line #143
```

Trying to track down the offending `meta-data` element tagged `Binary XML file line #143`, I find the following:

```
# aapt l -a zz.apk

AndroidManifest.xml
META-INF/CERT.RSA
META-INF/CERT.SF
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
...
Android manifest:
N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
  E: manifest (line=2)
    ...
    A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x19 (Raw: "25")
    A: platformBuildVersionName="7.1.1" (Raw: "7.1.1")
    ...
    E: meta-data (line=143)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.support.VERSION" (Raw: "android.support.VERSION")
      A: android:value(0x01010024)="25.3.1" (Raw: "25.3.1")
...
```

But I don't have anything like this in my `AndroidManifest.xml` and the only other reference to "25.3.1" is in my `gradle.build` file,  which are the dependency lines for the *Android Support Libraries*:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    ...
}
```

**What is the problem and why does this warning occur?**
(How do I resolve it?)

Comment: Turn off instant run.

Comment: @azizbekian I turned it off **and** downgraded the support library, back to 25.1.0, and the problem seem gone! Any ideas what is causing it?

Comment: So, if you change support libs to `25.3.1` it won't work?

Comment: Actually things are a bit more complicated, since package was rebased and both AS and libraries was updated within 2 days. I need to test it again, since I never used instant run and have no idea if it was off before the update. So how did you find out it may be related to instant run?

Comment: You see weird outputs that you have never expected to see - first thing you should think of is instant run.

Comment: @azizbekian Please post an answer that I can accept. I re-upped libraries and it still compiles fine. Another FUd source for strange behavior seem to be the `minifyEnabled true` which is out-of-the-box incompatible with ProGuard and also do not work with [various things](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#keep-code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Turning off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168753/instant-run-in-android-studio-2-0-how-to-turn-off) ***instant run*** feature would resolve the issue.