# run app vs apply changes android studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, toolbar, android-instant-run, instant-run

What is the major difference between

**Run app**  and  **Apply changes**?

[image]

What could be the best scenario to use each?

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**"Apply changes" will be enabled if you have "instant run" enabled** and to disable instant run check https://stackoverflow.com/a/35169716/2826147

From the Android documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html

> **Apply Changes  button provides a faster workflow for most incremental changes to your app.** [...]
>
> You can clickApply Changes  to push certain code and resource changes to your
>   running app without building a new APK—and, in some cases, without
>   even restarting the current activity. [...]
>
> Clicking **Run  (or Debug ) forces a cold swap and an app restart**.
>   If you make a change to the app manifest or a resource referenced by
>   the manifest, Android Studio always pushes your changes with a full
>   APK reinstall. [...]
>
> Apply Changes  action is available only when you meet the following conditions:
>
> - Build your app using a debug build variant.
> - Use Android plugin for Gradle version 2.3.0 or higher.
> - Set minSdkVersion to 15 or higher in your app's module-level
>     build.gradle file.
> - Deploy your app to a target device running Android 5.0 (API level 21)
>     and higher.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 4):

When you click "Run" App icon, it will uninstall existing build and install build every time.

"Apply Changes" option will be available only if you enable "Instant Run" feature in android studio. It will swap changes to existing build and run your build. Your existing build will not get uninstalled when you do this.

Answer (score 2):

The Instant Run / Apply Changes feature will try to push your changes without building and deploying a full APK, and if possible without restarting the application or even the current activity. It will resort to a full reinstall if needed. More details [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run).

Before Android Studio 2.3, the Instant Run feature was available through the Run (or Debug) button, as long as certain conditions were met. Starting with Studio 2.3 we have a dedicated button for Instant Run, which is the Apply Changes button. It is only available when Instant Run is possible. The Run and Debug button now always restart the app.

From the [Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html):

> A separate button to push changes with Instant Run: After deploying your  app, you now click Apply Changes to quickly push incremental changes to   your running app using Instant Run. The Run and Debug buttons are always  available to you when you want to reliably push your changes and force an app restart

Answer (score 2):

for Android Studio 3.5 and higher
[image]