# Android Studio start a wrong activity, but when clear data and cache of the app the app start as normal

Tags: android

As the title stated above, I've had no idea what else to do. When I  click the run button the app starts in a wrong activity, but when I clear the app data and cache and start manually on my phone it shows the intended activity I wanted. 
This is my manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/icon_logo"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@style/MyThemeNoBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" />
```

The app will directly go to MainActivity where it's based on Tabbed Activity from the template of Android Studio.

**EDIT**

Here is my SplashScreen code

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences settings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Create SharedPreferences to store token
        settings = getSharedPreferences("token", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //Check if user session is stored or not
        if (settings.getBoolean("connected", true)) {
        /* The user has already login, so start the dashboard */
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        Thread myThread = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(3000);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        myThread.start();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

OK, the flow of my app should be like this
SplashScreen -> MainActivity -> LoginActivity.
Currently the app skip past SplashScreen and goes directly to MainActivity.
Below are my build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.public.test"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.auth0.android:jwtdecode:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Are you using Instant Run in Android Studio?

Comment: @Bob usually i click on the green play icon, is that instant run?

Comment: Instant Run is enabled by default. Try disabling it. refer here to disable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35169716/4586742

Comment: @Bob Ok i just disabled the instant run and ran the app again, but no luck it's still show the MainActivity, I had also clean and build the project.

Comment: can you post your SplashScreen Activity code?

Comment: try this https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#activity-restart

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I had tried the 'Disable automatic activity restart' but it's still show the MainActivity, and by the way the Shared Preference aren't created yet as i already open root explorer to the app data storage.

Comment: Post your Build.gradle file

Comment: You have to specify what wrong activity means to you. Be more specific. We have no idea how you want your app to behave

Comment: I've posted my gradle and how i want my app to behave @TasosMoustakas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After intensive code analyzing, I've finally found what causes the problem. This line of code had been the problem that cause my page to start of a wrong activity.

```
if (settings.getBoolean("connected", true)) {
    /* The user has already login, so start the dashboard */
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

And the reason why it happend is because the if block detect the connect as true even when there is no SharedPref file was created in fresh deployment. The solution I've used is to change the if statement of `setting.getBoolean` to `setting.contain`

```
if (settings.contain("connected")) {
    /* The user has already login, so start the dashboard */
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

There is a strange feeling lingering in my mind as to why the `getBoolean()`return true even the "connected" had not been created yet, plus I also disabled the `android:allowBackup:"false"`that should had solve the problem. By the way thanks for all the response.

Answer (score 0):

try by doing something like this

in your manifest edit your splashScreen Activity Intent filter

```
<activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@style/MyThemeNoBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and in your MainActivity tag try using

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="your complete.name.package.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

ya change the name to wherever you have kept your main activity i.e full specified path