# Issue occurs in saving data in Android Sqlite database with multiple tables

Tags: android, save, android-sqlite

I followed a tutoral to develop a user registration form. By following that code I create another table call client and create other relevant classes. But once I click the save button, my application has stopped work. I try a lot to fix this error, but it does not work. Please if someone could help me to find this issue I really appreciate your help. Thank You

This is activity_client.xml file.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorBackground"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:text="@string/subhead"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <!--Company Name-->
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutCmpyName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextCmpyName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/hintCmpyName"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <!--Address-->
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutCmpyAddress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextAddress"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/hintCmpyAddress"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="5"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <!--Mobile-->
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutCmpyMobile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextMobile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/hintClientMobile"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="5"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!--Email-->

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutCmpyEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hintClientEmail"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="5"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/appCompatButtonBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="357dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
            android:background="@color/colorTextHint"
            android:text="@string/text_back" />

<!--save button-->       
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/appCompatButtonSave"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/appCompatButtonBack"


              android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/appCompatButtonBack"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="38dp"
                android:background="@color/colorTextHint"
                android:text="@string/text_save" />

        </RelativeLayout>

DataBaseHelper class in an package call dbclasses. Yhis class has code for both ClentInfo class and UserRegister class;another class.
```

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
    //Database version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Database1.db";

    //table names
    private static final String TABLE_USER = "user"; // User table name
    private static final String TABLE_CLIENT = "client";

 //Client Table Columns names
    private static final String COLUMN_CLIENT_ID = "client_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_CLIENT_NAME = "client_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_CLIENT_ADDRESS = "client_address";
    private static final String COLUMN_CLIENT_MOBILE = "client_mobile";
    private static final String COLUMN_CLIENT_EMAIL = "client_email";


    //create client table
    private String CREATE_CLIENT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CLIENT + "("
            + COLUMN_CLIENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + COLUMN_CLIENT_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_CLIENT_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_CLIENT_MOBILE + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_CLIENT_EMAIL + " TEXT"
            + ")";

    // drop table sql query
    private String DROP_USER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER;  //for user table
    private String DROP_CLIENT_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CLIENT;


public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
   db.execSQL(CREATE_CLIENT_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL(DROP_USER_TABLE);
   db.execSQL(DROP_CLIENT_TABLE);



    //create new tables


           onCreate(db);
        }

     //---------------------------client table methods--------------------
     //add user
        public void addClient(Client client) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_CLIENT_NAME, client.getCmpyName());
        values.put(COLUMN_CLIENT_ADDRESS, client.getAddress());
        values.put(COLUMN_CLIENT_MOBILE, client.getMobile());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL, client.getEmail());

        //Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CLIENT, null, values);
        db.close();
    }


    //get all clients
    public List<Client> getAllClients() {
        String columns1[] = {
                COLUMN_CLIENT_ID,
                COLUMN_CLIENT_NAME,
                COLUMN_CLIENT_ADDRESS,
                COLUMN_CLIENT_MOBILE,
                COLUMN_USER_EMAIL
        };

        //sorting orders
        String sortOrder = COLUMN_CLIENT_NAME + " ASC";
        List<Client> clientList = new ArrayList<Client>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CLIENT,
                columns1,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                sortOrder);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Client client = new Client();
                client.setCid(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CLIENT_ID))));
                client.setCmpyName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CLIENT_NAME)));
                client.setAddress(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CLIENT_ADDRESS)));
                client.setMobile(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CLIENT_MOBILE)));
                client.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CLIENT_EMAIL)));

                //adding clients to list
                clientList.add(client);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return clientList;
    }

//update the clients
    public void updateClient(Client client) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_CLIENT_NAME, client.getCmpyName());
        values.put(COLUMN_CLIENT_ADDRESS, client.getAddress());
        values.put(COLUMN_CLIENT_MOBILE, client.getMobile());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL, client.getEmail());

        //updating row
        db.update(TABLE_CLIENT, values, COLUMN_CLIENT_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{
                        String.valueOf(client.getCid())
                });

        db.close();
    }

    public boolean checkClient(String cmpyName) {
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_CLIENT_ID
        };
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String selection = COLUMN_CLIENT_NAME + " = ?";

        // selection argument
        String[] selectionArgs = {cmpyName};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CLIENT, //Table to query
                columns,                    //columns to return
                selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
                selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                       //group the rows
                null,                      //filter by row groups
                null);                      //The sort order
        int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        if (cursorCount > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

This is the ClientActivity Class in Client package

```
 package com.example.user.application001.Client;

    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
    import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
    import android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.example.user.application001.R;

    import dbclasses.DataBaseHelper;
    import modelclasses.Client;

    public class ClientActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

        private final AppCompatActivity activity = ClientActivity.this;

        private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
        private ClientValidation clientValidation;

        private Client client;


        //private NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;
        private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutCmpyName, textInputLayoutCmpyAddress, textInputLayoutCmpyMobile, textInputLayoutCmpyEmail;
        private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextCmpyName, textInputEditTextAddress, textInputEditTextMobile, textInputEditTextEmail;
        private AppCompatButton appCompatButtonSave, appCompatButtonBack;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_client);

            setTitle("Customer Information");

            initViews();
            initListeners();
            initObjects();

        }

        public void initViews() {

            //nestedScrollView = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.nestedScrollView);
            textInputLayoutCmpyName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutCmpyName);
            textInputLayoutCmpyAddress = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutCmpyAddress);
            textInputLayoutCmpyMobile = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutCmpyMobile);
            textInputLayoutCmpyEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutCmpyEmail);

            textInputEditTextCmpyName = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextCmpyName);
            textInputEditTextAddress = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextAddress);
            textInputEditTextMobile = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextMobile);
            textInputEditTextEmail = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextEmail);

            appCompatButtonSave = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.appCompatButtonSave);
            appCompatButtonBack = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.appCompatButtonBack);

        }

        public void initListeners() {
            appCompatButtonBack.setOnClickListener(this);
            appCompatButtonSave.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void initObjects() {

            clientValidation = new ClientValidation(activity);
            dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(activity);

            client = new Client();
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.appCompatButtonSave:
                    savetoSQliteDb();
                    break;
                case R.id.appCompatButtonBack:
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void savetoSQliteDb(){

            if (!clientValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextCmpyName, textInputLayoutCmpyName, getString(R.string.errorCmpyName))){
                return;
            }
            if (!clientValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextAddress, textInputLayoutCmpyAddress, getString(R.string.errorCmpyAddress))){
                return;
            }
            if (!clientValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextMobile, textInputLayoutCmpyMobile, getString(R.string.errorCustomerMobile))){
                return;
            }if (!clientValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextEmail, textInputLayoutCmpyEmail, getString(R.string.errorCustomerEmail))){
                return;
            }

            if (!dbHelper.checkClient(textInputEditTextCmpyName.getText().toString())){
                client.setCmpyName(textInputEditTextCmpyName.getText().toString().trim());
                client.setAddress(textInputEditTextAddress.getText().toString().trim());
                client.setMobile(textInputEditTextMobile.getText().toString().trim());
                client.setEmail(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim());

                //add one record
                dbHelper.addClient(client);
                emptyInputEditText();

               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Entered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }

        private void emptyInputEditText() {
            textInputEditTextCmpyName.setText(null);
            textInputEditTextAddress.setText(null);
            textInputEditTextMobile.setText(null);
            textInputEditTextEmail.setText(null);
        }

    }

This is the ClientValidation Java class. This is also in the client package



     package com.example.user.application001.Client;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
        import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.WindowManager;
        import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;

        /**
         * Created by User on 9/28/2017.
         */

        public class ClientValidation {

            private Context context;

            public ClientValidation(Context context) {
                this.context = context;
            }

            public  boolean isInputEditTextFilled(TextInputEditText textInputEditText, TextInputLayout textInputLayout, String message) {
                String value = textInputEditText.getText().toString().trim();
                if (value.isEmpty()) {
                    textInputLayout.setError(message);
                    hideKeyboardFrom(textInputEditText);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
                }
                return true;
            }
            private  void hideKeyboardFrom(View view) {

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

            }

        }

    This is the Client class. It is in modelclasses package.

    package modelclasses;

    /**
     * Created by User on 9/26/2017.
     */

    public class Client {

        private int cid;
        private String cmpyName;
        private String address;
        private String mobile;
        private String email;

        public int getCid() {
            return cid;
        }

        public void setCid(int cid) {
            this.cid = cid;
        }

        public String getCmpyName() {
            return cmpyName;
        }

        public void setCmpyName(String cmpyName) {
            this.cmpyName = cmpyName;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

        public String getMobile() {
            return mobile;
        }

        public void setMobile(String mobile) {
            this.mobile = mobile;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

    }
```

logcat

```
/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.user.application001-2@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
    09-29 08:29:01.252 4993-4993/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.user.application001-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.user.application001-2@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
    09-29 08:29:01.264 4993-4993/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.user.application001-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.user.application001-2@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
    09-29 08:29:01.276 4993-4993/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.user.application001-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.user.application001-2@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
    09-29 08:29:01.290 4993-4993/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.user.application001-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.user.application001-2@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
    09-29 08:29:01.305 4993-4993/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.user.application001-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.user.application001-2@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
    09-29 08:29:01.317 4993-4993/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.user.application001-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.user.application001-2@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
    09-29 08:29:01.318 4993-4993/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.user.application001-2/lib/x86
    09-29 08:29:01.320 4993-4993/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
    09-29 08:29:01.384 4993-4993/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
    09-29 08:29:01.495 4993-5038/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                     [ 09-29 08:29:01.497  4993: 4993 D/         ]
                                                     HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa4187280, tid 4993


                                                     [ 09-29 08:29:01.498  4993: 4993 W/         ]
                                                     Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 

                                                     [ 09-29 08:29:01.523  4993: 5038 D/         ]
                                                     HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaaffbd40, tid 5038


                                                     [ 09-29 08:29:01.524  4993: 5038 W/         ]
                                                     Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 
    09-29 08:29:01.526 4993-5038/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    09-29 08:29:01.526 4993-5038/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
    09-29 08:29:01.534 4993-5038/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xaf0635a0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
    09-29 08:29:01.535 4993-5038/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf0635a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaf0528e0)
    09-29 08:29:01.554 4993-5038/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf0635a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaf0528e0)
    09-29 08:29:01.610 4993-4993/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
```

Comment: You need to have a look at the exact error message for us to be able to help you. On Android Studio that's available usually under the debug/run tab on the bottom, or the logcat view also at the bottom of AS window. Usually the first few lines in red will be the most usefull ones, followed by pairs of filenames + line numbers that you can use to find where the problem is in your code.

Comment: @Fabio, I cannot find the error in my logcat regarding the saving of data

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling instant run until you get familiar with Android, this particular problem seems to come from instant run which is not quite stable yet as of the latest stable build (2.3.3):

In short, open Android Studio settings, type instant run on the search box and disable it.

This question covers how to do it:  [Instant run in Android Studio 2.0 (how to turn off)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168753/instant-run-in-android-studio-2-0-how-to-turn-off)

Comment: You need to be specific when you say you have an error. Does it crash? does it freeze? does it do nothing? does it not save data when it looks like it did? It's impossible to do guess work.

Comment: @Fa bio, When I click save button app displays, "Application has stopped work".  And then I cannot go forward and app stop working

Comment: Logcat must have something useful, start with that. The few lines you posted cover less than 1 second since your app started, scroll to see more. Also apply a breakpoint in the lines that you suspect are causing the problem . See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this and it wouldn't be a bad idea looking at some free courses like Udacity's

Comment: thank you since you're trying to help me. this is actually a part of the logcat. i can not post the whole logcat as I exceed the limit of characters. But i remove a small part of the logcat and post other part. I really caqn not find the reason for the issue

Comment: you can use https://pastebin.com/ for writing long logs and copy the generated link here