# cannot find symbol class ActivityNotificationsBinding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have created a new activity and used databinding to link UI and Code. The corresponding databinding class is generated and also imported. But, when building the project, it is showing this error: `Error:(6, 37) error: cannot find symbol class ActivityNotificationsBinding`.
I have invalidated and restarted the IDE also. Please let me know a fix to this issue and when am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

for solve this problem disable [instance run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168753/instant-run-in-android-studio-2-0-how-to-turn-off)

Comment: No its not working. Actually it is the problem with viewmodel. When I am calling a function using viewModel object then this error is popping up.