# StrictMode disk read violation on empty activity's setContentView

Tags: android, oncreate, android-instant-run, android-strictmode

I've recently tried to use StrictMode but got a weird violation, so I tried setting up a **new** 'Empty Activity' project (in `Android Studio`) and added an Application class as follows (as described in [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode)):

```
public class TestApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        setStrictMode();
        super.onCreate();

    }

    private void setStrictMode() {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .detectAll()
                    .penaltyLog()
                    .build());
            StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                    .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
                    .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
                    .penaltyLog()
                    .penaltyDeath()
                    .build());
        }
    }
}
```

I have the same problem in this empty project:
`StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=165 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=65599 violation=2`

Stack:

```
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1440)
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:241)
at java.io.File.isDirectory(File.java:837)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList$Element.toString(DexPathList.java:634)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2827)
at java.util.Arrays.toString(Arrays.java:4511)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.toString(DexPathList.java:194)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2827)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:132)
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:126)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onResourcesLoaded(DecorView.java:1933)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2586)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2659)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2067)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:374)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:323)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
at com.test.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

**The question(s):**
Is this a configuration problem?
If not, can I make StrictMode ignore specific method calls (it happens on a `layoutInflater.inflate` call as well on the original project)?

---

**Edit** (add configuration):
Android Studio version: 3.1.3
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 27
appcompat-v7:27.1.1
Device: Nexus 6p

**Edit2** (solution):
I realized that the solution by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) is somewhat hidden in his comment below, so: it was the [instant run enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35169716/4759619) that caused my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this a configuration problem?

Probably not, at least in terms of configuring `StrictMode`.

I tried reproducing your case, using your `TestApplication` class and a new `minSdkVersion 19` project, and I could not reproduce the results, testing on a Google Pixel 2.

Possible sources of the crash include:

- Something different about the version of Android on your device (e.g., manufacturer tweaks that the Pixel 2 lacks)
- Something different about the version of `appcompat-v7` in your project (mine wound up with `28.0.0-alpha3`)
- Something else different about your project (the crash feels like a support multidex issue)
- **UPDATE** Something different about your development environment — in this case, Instant Run seems to be the culprit, based on the comments

> can I make StrictMode ignore specific method calls

Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Thanks the quick response (added configuration for reference); I'll test on 28 although I doubt I'll use it in the original project (for now)

Comment: @MikeL: If you're running the Nexus 6P, it shouldn't be a device issue, unless you installed a custom ROM. I just reconfigured my project to match yours (plus `compileSdkVersion 27`), fired up my 6P, and I cannot reproduce the problem. I am using the same version of Studio, though I always have Instant Run disabled. If you have Instant Run enabled, you might try disabling it and seeing if you get different results.